# This CSP errors drives me crazy

Tags: javascript, css, content-security-policy

Edited this question because it became very confusing and I tried to put all the facts in line:

1. I have two websites, hosted on the same server with an external hosting provider. No CSP was set for either one!
2. My primary site experiences no issues, the development site does with animations from an external css...
3. Issues are errors in the browser console concerning the refusal to load scripts and CSS.
4. After I found out about the errors I started troubleshooting and it became more and more unclear.
5. When I put a CSP header in the HTAccess file, it does get mentioned in the browser console as reason to block stuff.
6. As soon as my CSP is less restrictive than "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' It falls back to the latter.
7. When I completely remove the CSP line in HTAccess, the browser and external policy evaluator mentions find a csp "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'. On the production website they don't.
8. I use Joomla as CMS and wouldn't know any other place to set the CSP as in the HTAccess file, the index.php-file or on the server. The server can be ruled out since my other site is there too and the index.php file and the htaccessfile I can control myself.
9. Weirdest is that the browser seems to execute both as seen in this picture. Note that the first and third line mention that style-src-elem is not set while the second line mentions being in conflict with that same directive.

[image]

This is my htaccess code:

```
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "Default-src 'self' https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' ; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' ; style-src-elem 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ "
```

I know the "Unsafe-inline" is not what I want, but I first want to fix the errors and then the rest.

This is part of the code from the index.php:

```
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Inline icons to use -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/brands.css" integrity="sha384-Px1uYmw7+bCkOsNAiAV5nxGKJ0Ixn5nChyW8lCK1Li1ic9nbO5pC/iXaq27X5ENt" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/solid.css" integrity="sha384-osqezT+30O6N/vsMqwW8Ch6wKlMofqueuia2H7fePy42uC05rm1G+BUPSd2iBSJL" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/fontawesome.css" integrity="sha384-BzCy2fixOYd0HObpx3GMefNqdbA7Qjcc91RgYeDjrHTIEXqiF00jKvgQG0+zY/7I" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.0.0/animate.min.css" ntegrity="sha256-HtCCUh9Hkh//8U1OwcbD8epVEUdBvuI8wj1KtqMhNkI=" crossorigin="anonymous"/> 
     <script src="/libraries/google/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="/libraries/google/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
```

So, please help me before I go insane...

Comment: The error message tells you that `style-src-elem` is not set. You aren't setting it. You are setting `style-src`. (Voting to close because the problem is caused by a typo)

Comment: @Quentin `style-src` is *supposed* to be the first fallback if `style-src-elem` is not set. I think it's more likely that the policy is not successfully making it to the browser.

Comment: Thanks guys. However, In FF the console mentions the policy content, so it is reaching the browser. The typo part I don't understand, because the style-src rules shoudl allow, as @pointy states?

Comment: Have you verified via the browser "Network" tab?

Comment: `"default-src 'self'` doesn't mention the domains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!! It was in my cookiehint plugin.

Switched it off and now it works as expected.